# Can I download free apps without a payment method?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, applications, ios-appstore

I just downloaded the newest iOS version, which I don't know what it is, and I can't download free apps now. I used to be able to download free apps, but now apple requires a credit card to download apps even if the apps are free.

I don't know what version of iOS I am using, nor what type I was using earlier. Nor do I know what type of iPhone I am using other than that it is an iPhone of some sort. I don't know how to find out this information either.

Answer (score 0):

This official guide can help you:
[Create or use your Apple ID without a payment method](https://support.apple.com/HT204034)

If you already have an Apple ID
You can choose to remove the payment method for your existing Apple ID after you have signed in to the iTunes Store, App Store, or iBooks Store. You won't be asked for a payment method again until you make a purchase. Have a look at: [Change or remove your Apple ID payment information](https://support.apple.com/HT201266)

Comment: That doesn't help in the slightest. It's saying that if I don't want to add a credit card I need to add credit card information. What I'm asking is why that's the case.

Comment: do you have an apple id?

Comment: Yes, I do have an apple ID.

Comment: So have you try to modify with Itunes your Account Information payment method?

Comment: Yes, I have. It asked for credit card information after I pressed "no payment method", as it said it would on the link you provided.

Comment: if you do not fall under any circumstances: [If you can‘t choose None when you edit your Apple ID payment informatio](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203905) it would cover you to create a new apple id